# While connecting in LAN i m having 3 dns, how to configure my android studio with the particular dns

Tags: android, dns, android-studio-3.3

My Android Emulator Wifi is not getting connected via LAN Connection. But in Wifi i am able to get it connected. When i tried to identify the dns available in my LAN. It is displaying 3 dns connections. How to identify which dns i need to configure, to make my Android Emulator to get connected with LAN.

Can someone please provide your solutions or possible methods for this problem.

Comment: Title says "how to configure", question says "which dns I need to configure". If you just need to choose one of the 3... why haven't you tested it?

Comment: Thanks James, i have already tried by connecting each dns separately and verified. But not able to connect my Wifi in Android Emulator with LAN Connected to my MAC PC. Error message displayed : DNS not connected properly